# Is there a case when declaring a variable without initializing it would make it non-undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

If we declare a variable without an initial value, the value will be `undefined`:

```
var foo;
foo;
// → undefined
```

But, is there a case (e.g. some old browser, or maybe a special environment) where when declaring a variable, this variable could have a value different than `undefined`?

I am just thinking why in some cases we use `void 0` instead of undefined to check against `undefined`?

```
// Why this...
if (foo === void 0) {
  // ...
}

// and not this?
var U;
if (foo === U) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: There is basically undefined and not-defined

Comment: `(() => { const undefined = 'baz'; console.log('baz' === undefined) })()`

Comment: @ThanveerShah While that is a difference to keep in mind (one will cause a `ReferenceError`, the other won't), the question is asking about something else

Comment: @CertainPerformance One of the answers in the question you linked mine as duplicate says _`window.undefined` is writable whereas void operator will always return undefined_ — I'm sorry, but I can't understand how `window.undefined` can be overridden...

Comment: It's not possible in modern browsers, thankfully, but it *used* to be. But defining a variable named `undefined` is still a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override `window.undefined`.

This used to be possible in the past, in some browsers, but not it's not possible anymore.

Like mentioned in the comments you can create an `undefined` variable like this:

```
(() => { 
    const undefined = 'baz';
    console.log('baz' === undefined) 
})()
```